# How to fix this triangel function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

i am so newbie in programming, what i want is create a file which able automatically count triangel around (actually this is pythagoras problem).

i had tried to code with simple programming (the result is written below), and use function in javascript.
i use simple html file to call the javascript file, but the result is always wrong.

```
function fungsiKllSegitiga1(a,b) {

    var c = Math.SQRT(a * a + b * b);
    var kll=a+b+c;
    return c.sqrt;
}

function fungsiKllSegitiga2(a,b) {

    var c = (a * a + b * b)^(0.5);
    var kll=a+b+c;
    return c.sqrt;
}
```

i want variable c to count pythagoras, but i can't do it properly. any suggestion?

Comment: This should achieve what you require: `const fungsiKllSegitiga1 = (a,b) => Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function fungsiKllSegitiga1(a,b) {
  var c = Math.SQRT(a * a + b * b);
  return c;
}

fungsiKllSegitiga1(tmp, tmp)
```

`tmp` means temporary, change it to the numbers you want.